# How to handle an issue that is not easily recreated?

Tags: windows-7, bsod, nvidia-graphics-card

My (asus) laptop randomly gives a bsod error at startup. Not always. Few times a week.

> This was probably caused by the following module: nvlddmkm.sys (nvlddmkm+0x374823)
>   Google query: NVIDIA Corporation SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M

I have of course updated drivers, cleared the drivers using safemode reinstalled it, tried so many things but nothing worked. There is no known solution as far as I can tell.

So when I take this laptop to the service, what can they do? They'll turn the computer on, and it will not give a bsod. They restart it, it will not give a bsod (it gives bsod only after it has been turned on after some time)

It seems as though they'll simply reinstall windows and give it back to me without doing anything.

What should I do?

I have tried extracting nvlddmkm.sy_ and replacing the one in system32

I have added TdrDelay and TdrDdiDelay to registry

I cleaned all drivers in safe mode and reinstalled the driver.

Comment: when the service people reinstall windows and send it back to you, then if you get another BSOD - particularly the same one, tell them and send it back and if in warranty they'll  likely either replace a part inside it or replace the whole thing

Comment: And I don't know why you say there are no known fixes for it. There are 200K results for nvlddmkm.sys    and 9K results for "This was probably caused by the following module:" nvlddmkm.sys.   So at least try 5-10 of them

Comment: @barlop none of which works

Comment: There could be tons of things there for example  this sevenforums thread http://www.sevenforums.com/bsod-help-support/302270-bsod-playing-games-only-nvlddmkm-sys-error.html says in FF to do unchecking the option to "use hardware acceleration when available) in Firefox>>Tools>>Options>>Advanced>>General (tab)>Browsing.    Which probably won't work, but you should really keep a log of everything you tried and list it.  That solved it for him.. So saying no known solution isn't really clear.. Especially when there is so much out there.

Comment: Anyhow, i'm not suggesting trying everything.. just saying that rather than saying you tried a lot, you should list what you tried. And that the service company would replace it or a part, if reinstalling windows didn't work. (so tha's in answer to your question of what they would do).

Comment: I have tried extracting nvlddmkm.sy_ and replacing the one in system32 |||||||||||||||||||||||


I have added TdrDelay and TdrDdiDelay to registry||||||||||||||||||||||||||

I cleaned all drivers in safe mode and reinstalled the driver.|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||


My problem happens right when windows is booted. After it bsods, the fan starts to work very fast (indefinitely), until it is restarted again, so I turn it off and on.

Comment: which driver version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I recommend, from what I can tell that you've tried so far.

Before proceeding - back up all your data, and make sure you have all the license/installation keys for all your purchased software.

- If it's under warranty, have the repair company restore the system to factory defaults.  Also, maybe take a picture when it BSODs, so they can see you're telling the truth.  They should be able to see it in the System logs too, but if they're lazy or incompetent, you can show it to them.
- If it's not under warranty, if you have the installation DVD or recovery partition, follow ASUS' instructions, if they have any.  If not, hopefully the following instructions will work for you... http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/choosing-an-advanced-recovery-method.  If that doesn't work, take it in to your ASUS authorized computer service center and pay for them to restore to factory defaults. (If it's more than 3 years old, consider buying a new laptop)

Essentially, based on what you've tried so far, you're not likely to find the culprit.  I've probably spent hundreds of hours, if not thousands, troubleshooting similar issues on dozens of computers over the years.  If you can't find it in the first few hours or so, it's usually much faster to just wipe and start over.

Also...

You can run a disk scan or use the system file checker - Microsoft KB articles 2641432 and 929833  (Sorry – I'd post the links, but this site won't let me post more than 2 links until I have 10 reputation.  Geez!)  There's a lot of other things you can try, but it all depends on how much time you have to spend on it.